# Flux flatMap backpressure

Tags: java, project-reactor

How to apply backpressure to limit a `Publisher` from producing more items than a `flatMap` running in parallel can handle?

### 1. Setup

For illustration purpose, there's a fast twitter username generator, a slow twitter lookup call, a slow twitter file writer and a print method.

```
private Consumer<FluxSink<String>> twitterUsernameGenerator() {
    return (sink) -> Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "d").forEach(sink::next);
}

private Flux<TwitterMessage>findTwitterMessagesByUsername() {
    return Flux.create(sink -> {
            sink.next(new TwitterMessage(...));
            sleep(2000);
            sink.next(new TwitterMessage(...));
        }
    });
}

private void print(Object o) {
    System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] " + o);
}
```

**The end goal** is to run twitter lookup in parallel while applying backpressure to the generator to not emit more username than can be handled (some prefetching is expected).

### 2. Generating twitter usernames

```
Flux.create(twitterUsernameGenerator())
    .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
    .doOnNext(this::print)
    .subscribe();
```

This nicely produces 5 twitter usernames on a single, separate thread

```
[single-1] a
[single-1] b
[single-1] c
[single-1] d
```

### 3. Looking up twitter messages

Not sure it's correct, but I reason that, `flatMap` to produce many twitter messages from one username and `parallel` to perform this **I/O intensive** operation on two threads.

```
Flux.create(twitterUsernameGenerator())
    .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
    .doOnNext(this::print)
    .parallel(2)
    .runOn(Schedulers.newParallel("p", 2))
    .flatMap(username -> findTwitterMessagesByUsername(username))
    .doOnNext(this::print)
    .subscribe();
```

WOAH! The generator produces usernames quicker than we can handle.

```
[single-1] a
[single-1] b
[single-1] c
[single-1] d
[p-1] TwitterMessage{...}
[p-2] TwitterMessage{...}
...
```

### 3. Applying backpressure to the generator

How can I apply backpressure to the generator function so the outcome becomes closer to this

```
[single-1] a
[single-1] b
[p-1] TwitterMessage{...}
[single-1] c
[p-2] TwitterMessage{...}
[single-1] d
...
```

Comment: did you figure that out? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Backpressure happens in "batches" bigger than 4 elements. If you modify generator to produce more usernames, e.g.

```
  private Consumer<FluxSink<String>> twitterUsernameGenerator() {
        return (sink) -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100000)
                .boxed().map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(sink::next);
    }
```

resulting flux will behave somewhat similar to the expected one.

You can play with adding `onBackpressureError()` to original Flux:

```
Flux.create(twitterUsernameGenerator())
        .onBackpressureError()
        .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
        .....
```

which will clearly signalize when backpressure occurs by throwing a exception.